# How can I use a javascript || with ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set a class like this:

```
ng-class="{fa-disabled: cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}"
```

What I would like is for the fa-disabled class to be added if cursorWait == true or if the wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled function returns true.

But this is giving me a run timer error:

> ```
> angular.js:13236 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 4 of the expression [{fa-disabled:
> ```
>
> cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}] starting at [-disabled:
>   cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}].
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/syntax?p0=-&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=4&p3=%7Bfa-disabled%3AursorWait%20%7C%7C%20wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)%7D&p4=-disabled%3A%cursorWait%20%7C%7C%20wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)%7D

Can someone help and advise what is wrong?

Comment: try ng-class="{'fa-disabled': cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is failing because it's not valid to use `-` in an object's property name unless the name is quoted.

Try

```
ng-class="{'fa-disabled': cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your class name in single quotes within `ng-class`:

```
ng-class="{'fa-disabled': cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Class should be in single quotes if it has '-' in between.

```
ng-class="{'fa-disabled': cursorWait || wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)}"
```